# Color problems with pandas matplotlib - graph colors are inconsistent

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have graphs with just 3 colors - Green, Red, Grey for values A, B, C. The application uses group by and value counts to get the cumulative count of A, B, and C across months and shows a donut chart, barh, and a bar chart. The colors shift from graph to graph - on one they A is green and the other graph with the same data shows A as red.

Simple fix, right?

```
def color_for_label(label):
    xlate = {'A': 'green',
             'B': 'red',
             'C': 'grey',
             }
    return [xlate[x] for x in label]


chart = gb.unstack(level=-1)
               .plot.barh(color=color_for_label(gb.index[0:2].names), 
                width=.50,
                stacked=True, 
                legend=None)
```

The data returns an index sometimes and a multiindex other times. It chokes on  and  but works on

The colors are constant Red/Green/Grey that always go with the values A/B/C.

I've tried checking datatypes and try/except structures, but both got too complex quickly. Anyone got a simple solution to share?

Lets use the data from this example [pandas pivot table to stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799718/pandas-pivot-table-to-stacked-bar-chart)

df.assign(count =1 ).groupby(['battle_type']).count().plot.barh(stacked=True)

and (latter preferred - I'm not loving the groupby inconsistencies)

```
df.pivot_table(index='battle_type', columns='attacker_outcome', aggfunc='size').plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

both get me

[image]

I have a 3rd value, "Tie" in my example of A, B, C above, but lets ignore that for the moment.

I want to make sure that win is always green, lose is red, Tie is grey.

so I have my simple function

```
def color_for_label(label):
    xlate = {'win': 'green',
             'lose': 'red',
             'Tie': 'grey',
             }
return xlate[label]
```

so I add

....`plot.barh(stacked=True, color=color_for_label(**label**))`

And here I'm stuck - what do I set label to so that win is always green, lose is red and tie is grey?

Comment: You probably need to make sure the index is in the same order for each of your plot, and/or use `matplotlib` directly to give you more flexibility. I cannot help more without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide mock-up data. In particular, refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

First, translate colors for the new example

```
def color_for_label(label):
    xlate = {'win': 'green',
             'loss': 'red',
             'tie': 'grey',
             }
    return [xlate[x] for x in label]
```

Then break it into two lines.

```
# create a dataframe
gb = df.pivot_table(index='battle_type', columns='attacker_outcome', aggfunc='size')
```

[image]

```
# pass the dataframe column values
gb.plot.barh(stacked=True, color=color_for_label(gb.columns.values))
```

[image]

Comment: see https://medium.com/dunder-data/minimally-sufficient-pandas-a8e67f2a2428?mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiWTJOaFl6Vm1OMlJsTlRKbCIsInQiOiIrM1RsTW0yanV5WGcxZE5zWTdacXh6WWFaNmpkQ1NkSnR1WGRKQThxTU8rZnVZd1FXN3h2cjF3NEYzUjYrdzhmMHNxSmJramltcDlucmxTYmcxSUluOVBUaEJtYVMzaXBqWVFVd2s2T3pPTlBTa2VKOWVLRGJ2QVJWdW4yNkVKdiJ9 for additional info on why I switched to pivottable